# subprocess and exchanging json: How can I use read() on stdin non-blockingly?

Tags: python, json, subprocess

I have a main process, that sends json structured data to a subprocess. The subprocess is working with this data and giving back information on the progress in a percentage to the main process (which shall update a progress bar in the user interface).

The problem is, that the output of the subprocess is only received by the main process when the subprocess is already finished. It blocks on the read()-Statement I suppose. How can I get the main process to work with the response, as soon as child process posts a line to its stdout?

Here's the minimal working example:

*parent.py*

```
from json import dumps
import subprocess
from time import sleep

lines_to_exchange = ["this is line one", "this is line two", "this is line three", "this is line four", "this is line five"]
command = ["python", "-u", "./child.py"]
print("start process")


sub = subprocess.Popen(command, text=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

sub.stdin.write(dumps(lines_to_exchange))
sub.stdin.close()


while True:
    sleep(0.1)
    stdout = sub.stdout.read()
    print(stdout)

    if sub.poll() is not None:
        print("process completed")
        break
```

*child.py*

```
from time import sleep
from json import loads
import sys
lines = loads(input())

for line in lines:
    sleep(1)
    print(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I am working on Windows with python 3.10 and pycharm IDE.

Comment: `lines = loads(input())` is already blocking. Anything you do after that point doesn't matter.

Comment: It's _possible_ to use a streaming JSON parser, but honestly a lot more work than switching to JSONL as your data format, which will make line buffering (and line-oriented reads) work the way you intend "naturally".

Comment: (ahh -- I was looking at the wrong side, before realizing that you _intend_ to have the child read all its stdin before it writes any stdout. `sub.stdout.read()` is a problem too; compare to `sub.stdout.readline()` -- though to really operate a line at a time you need to either move to a file format that lets you know the data size you need, or read a byte at a time and eat the extra overhead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Use `os.set_blocking(fd, False)` for non-blocking reads.

---

What a great question!
Kudos for offering an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a nice educational way.

---

I really like the {while True, sleep epsilon} safety measure.
Always a good practice to unconditionally sleep a moment,
so buggy code won't accidentally peg a core.

---

nit: The explicit `.flush()` is very nice.
Some folks like to make it part of the print: `print(line, flush=True)`

The `-u` unbuffered flag is redundant with the explicit flush.
But sure, I get it, you were throwing everything at it
in hopes of making it work, cool.

In any event, the child is behaving perfectly.

---

The parent is *almost* correct, you're very close.
What's tripping you up is that child produces several
small messages totaling less than a hundred bytes,
and parent is defaulting to a large buffer.

To see this, change `.read()` to e.g. `.read(10)`.

Here is one default buffer size setting:

```
>>> import select
>>> select.PIPE_BUF
512
```

---

What you really want is non-blocking I/O in the parent.
Here is some setup that elsewhere I have tested as working:

```
    with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE) as sub:
        stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sub.stdout)
        fd = stdout.fileno()
        os.set_blocking(fd, False)
```

Feel free to discard the complexity of
a line-oriented wrapper if you don't need that.
The critical item is to set non-blocking,
as that alters the behavior of `.read()`.

We have an opportunity to replace
the "polling" `sleep()` with a call to `select()`,
which will pause for *exactly* the right amount
of time and wake up immediately upon data being ready.

```
            select([fd], [], [], timeout.total_seconds())
```

That last safety-valve parameter can be any value
suitably large,
say 30 seconds if you believe child will always
have something to say within that interval.

Now when you `.read()`,
or perhaps `.read(PIPE_BUF)` with explicit buffer size,
it will complete immediately since it is non-blocking.
This means it *can* return zero bytes,
and often will return fewer bytes than you asked for.
That's ok, just process the bytes and go back
to looping if child is still alive.

---

Note that the parent code you posted has a
race condition; it may not read everything
the child said. Do some final reads after child
death to ensure that nothing is lost.
Parent's responsibility is to keep reading
until EOF on that file descriptor.

Comment: Hi J_H, thank you very much for your detailed answer! read(10) helped and I then "buffered" the returned bytes until a newline came (in the real application I also return a JSON back from the child to the parent). I then figured out that readline() also did the job and did exactly what I wanted, hadn't tried it out before. the os.set_blocking seems to exist only on UNIX systems, not on windows. Regards!

Comment: Uggh! No non-blocking reads?!? Yikes. Ok, that seems to strongly motivate having the child try two complementary strategies: Promise to always offer "heartbeat" output at predictable intervals, and prefix each line of output with length of that line. For example, `n = 2 + len(line); return f'{n:05d}:{line}\n'`. Then parent issues `read(5)` followed by `read(n)`.